# Is the site re-design for the Mass Effect 3 promotion permanent?

Tags: support, design

The new site design looks fantastic, I think the giant animated robot was my favorite part.

I understand that it was created for the Mass Effect 3 promotion - but is the majority of the site design permanent, minus the "Mass Effect 3" promotional banner?

Comment: From what I understand, the Ask Question mothership will fire lazers on hover from now on.  However, I believe the rest of the design will revert to its pre-ME3 promotion state after the promotion ends.

Comment: I'm sure the ME3 related stuff like the giant animated robot at the bottom will be removed in addition to the banner itself.

Comment: I love the guns on top of the tabs (Questions, etc.) that shoot on mouse over as well, they should stay.

Comment: Another vote for the guns on top of the tabs staying.. We need to defend the site from those evil UFO questions some how!! :)

Comment: Can we keep one of the Makos?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no, a lot of the cool design changes for the Mass Effect 3 promotion were not kept around.

It's also worth noting that Arqade has since had a slight redesign to fit Stack Exchange's [unified theming changes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182), with the default Galaga/Pixels/Spaaace! theming sticking around.